# Bluetooth HSP profile backward

Tags: bluetooth-audio

I am deaf and use a cochlear implant and a hearing aid.

I have a device called a "microlink" which acts as a bluetooth 1.1 headset (amongst other things) and transmits audio received via BT to FM whence it is received by tiny FM receivers attached to my CI and HA.

This PHONAK Microlink device was expensive and works fine as a mobile phone headset (HSP profile), but when I had a NOKIA E series phone I could also play music from the phone's media player - which was fantastic!

Now, I have a Blackberry and a Nexus 7 and neither of them will send audio other than a phone call via the HSP profile, I assume they insist on A2DP for audio.

This is crippling to me, since I cannot now listen to music from either of my Blackberry or Nexus 7 without being wired up to it (or using a direct connection to the Microlink).

I cannot believe in this age of backward compatibility that there cannot be some way of sending media player output to (mono) bluetooth HSP as used to be the case.

Also, since the NEXUS 7 is not a phone - what the heck is the use of HSP on the device? (which shows in the profile list) - a nice port of Android, but why does it still think it's a phone!?

I came across an entry in some list some time ago (that I can't find now!) talking about being able to enter some secret AT string or something to a phone which caused it to redirect audio (from its speaker) to HSP bluetooth - does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: [BTmono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono) and [BlueMusic app](http://teksoftco.com/index.php?section=product&pid=30) might do this.  
Can you leave feedback when/if you tested it? 

Here's a question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144694/routing-audio-to-bluetooth-headset-non-a2dp-on-android) (for the programming part).